# How to Identify the local printers from network printers from my application

Tags: printing, powerbuilder

we have an application written in powerbuilder. We want a way to Identify the local printers from network printers in order to choose where to sent the printing. No problem if you have a solution in another programming language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the built in function PrintGetPrinters. It gives a list of the printers. Take a look at the 'port' value. Network printers will have Ne00: or Ne01:. I don't have a local printer but I am guessing they might be LPT1:. Not sure about USB printers. Try the function and see what it returns.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't even know about PrintGetPrinters that Roland mentioned. Not sure how I missed it but I recall getting list of all printers from Registry via RegistryGet. Maybe that version of PB didn't have the function. :)